# An insert query inserts only one row

Tags: sql

When I try to use this :

```
insert into mytable1 
  (whatever) 
values 
  (select whatever from mytable2 where accomplished=True);
```

Only one row gets inserted though there should be 3.

Why is this ?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question, because you've posted nonsense. Post your actual SQL statement, sample data, and what you expect the result to be. We can't tell what's wrong, because you've posted the equivalent of `Blah blah blah` doesn't work. Why? If you want help, post something that is realistic. There is a specific close reason here for posts that say *This code doesn't work* without posting the actual code for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, the statement you have above inserts into one row as many values as you have fields in the `(whatever)` part.

You should try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Check this site out for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because it benefits no one (now or in the future) to answer this kind of nonsensical post. If the poster wants help, they can put the effort into asking a better question. There is no benefit here to keeping garbage. (I'd add a second downvote if I could for posting a link to w3schools.)

Comment: Thanks Ken, that really helped both me and user3181689.

Comment: Fantastic! I've accomplished my goal, which is to negatively affect the posting of excrement here. Thanks for acknowledging my efforts! Maybe you can participate in that effort, too! If @user3181689 wants help, user3181689 can post a real question with the actual code rather than a `(whatever) select (whatever from whatever)` question.

Comment: I figured since it's just userXXXX it means that the user did go through the effort to create an account, which is a bit more work than Google-ing the answer. From the content of the user's question, I could tell that he/she was headed down the wrong path, so I showed them the proper way. Commenting on questions as "excrement" discourages people from using the site and creates tension; when instead, one can help the user, make them feel good about using StackOverflow, and at the same time enrich this site with more content.

Comment: You're right. Commenting on excrement questions does in fact discourage people from posting crap here. I want to do so, as do the rest of the SO community. Creating an account takes zero effort, as is evident by the hundreds of thousands of accounts that have a reputation of 1 - in this case, the user didn't even bother to invent a user name, but went with the default `userXXXXXXX`. SO is designed to create a repository of **knowledge**, not noise. If the poster isn't willing to exert the effort to ask the question, there's no attempt to *enrich the site*.

Comment: We can continue to discuss the site's quality standards, if you'd like, after you review the [tour] and spend some time in the [help] and [meta], and have some experience here with the quality standards. If you want to exchange profile reviews, I'll be glad to do so. Congratulations for your acceptance of paper to cover the pile of offal.